# Getting a syntax error when I want to delete row based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have my dataframe `df_daily` and I’d like to check for duplicates based on my date column which corresponds to `df_daily[0]` and those rows that would be duplicates due to having the same date I’d like for them to be deleted and maintain only what is not a duplicate. I tried the following but am getting syntax error.

```
dp_check = df_daily.drop[df_daily[df_daily[0].drop_duplicates(keep = False)].index, inplace = True]
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_daily = pd.DataFrame({0:[4,5,4,6,5,8]})

dp_check = df_daily[~df_daily[0].duplicated(keep = False)]
```

Or [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with subset parameter:

```
dp_check = df_daily.drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep = False)

print (dp_check)
   0
3  6
5  8
```